# What should be the condition in if-else, if the prompt is null or entered further without entering any data?

Tags: javascript

If I enter nothing in prompt appearing and enter "OK", I am not getting "Invalid Name" appearing on the windows. It says nothing.

```js
let firstName = prompt("What is your name?!", '')
firstName != undefined ? alert(firstName) : alert("Invalid")
```

Comment: Do a  `console.log(firstName)`, an `alert(JSON.stringify(firstName));`, or a `debugger;`.

Comment: The prompt result will be `null` only if you hit cancel. If you enter nothing, you will get an empty string. So use `firstName != ""` as the condition

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `firstName` variable is defined as an empty string. 
If you want your alert to return `invalid` you should check against `firstName.length > 0` and also add `firstName &&` to the condition so it works also for the `cancel` prompt action when `firstName` returns `null`

```js
let firstName = prompt("What is your name?!", '')
firstName  && firstName.length > 0 ? alert(firstName) : alert("Invalid")

// examples
let x;
console.log(typeof x) //undefined
x = '';
console.log(typeof x) //string
```

Comment: @TylerRoper Yep. So adding `firstName  &&` to the condition does the trick. I was just giving the solution for the OP's question about `invalid` not showing when clicking `ok`. But thank you for the observation